# Should I put nginx proxy caches in the container or a volume?

Tags: docker, nginx, caching

For Docker, is it better to use the container's space as a proxy cache or a volume mount?  The cache data is pretty much ephemeral and if I lose it, it is not an issue.

I am just planning to use nginx as a SSL termination point for github pages which are not SSL under my domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a cache requires high i/o performance, you should definitely go for a volume.
The filesystem in the container is composed of multiple image layers and the current container layer. This usually leads to poor i/o performance.
In contrast, the volume data is directly stored on the host's file system, without any layering.